# How to get uri from connection_id inside a python script in Airflow?

Tags: docker, connection, uri, airflow

I have been following this official documentation https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html
to try to set up connections in Airflow. I want to access the uri of the connections in my python scripts so that I can work with my databases.

`airflow connections get sqlite_default` in bash gives me details of the connection.
I want to do a similar thing inside python script. How can it be possible?

I have saved my airflow connections from the UI as is mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone trying to figure this out, I was able to get the uri with the following steps :

1. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html shows how to store connections in Airflow
2. To get the connection uri

```
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
BaseHook.get_connection(CONN_ID).get_uri()
```

assuming `CONN_ID` is the name of the saved connection.